# how to remove string redundant in python

Tags: python

I need your help, can anyone tells me that what this part of code is doing?

```
if line[-6:] == '[edit]':
            state = line[:-6]
```

and

```
town = line[:(line.index('(')-1)]
```

the whole code is :

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    '''Returns a DataFrame of towns and the states they are in from the 
    university_towns.txt list. The format of the DataFrame should be:
    DataFrame( [ ["Michigan", "Ann Arbor"], ["Michigan", "Yipsilanti"] ], 
    columns=["State", "RegionName"]  )

    The following cleaning needs to be done:

    1. For "State", removing characters from "[" to the end.
    2. For "RegionName", when applicable, removing every character from " (" to the end.
    3. Depending on how you read the data, you may need to remove newline character '\n'. '''         
    with open('university_towns.txt') as file:
        data = []
        for line in file:
            data.append(line[:-1])

#     print(data)
    state_town = []
    for line in data:
        if line[-6:] == '[edit]':
            state = line[:-6]
#             print(state)
        elif '(' in line:
            town = line[:(line.index('(')-1)]
#             print(town)
            state_town.append([state,town])
        else:
            town = line.rstrip()
            state_town.append([state,town])
#     print(state_town)
    ans = pd.DataFrame(state_town, columns = ['State','RegionName']) 
    return ans
get_list_of_university_towns()
```

Comment: `line[-6:]` is just the last 6 characters of `line` (a negative index is relative to the right of the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if line[-6:] == '[edit]':
            state = line[:-6]
```

Is simply checking if last 6 character of given string are a `[edit]`, if so then this value is assigned to a `state` var.

```
town = line[:(line.index('(')-1)]
```

Here the `town` var gets the value of a characters of a line that are in front of `(` excluding.

EDIT:
Lets split this like:

```
index_to_par = line.index('(')
town = line[:(index_to_par - 1)]
```

So `index_to_par` is getting index on `line` string of a first `(`
Example if we have string like `some string (example)` then we get a value of `12` because `(` is on a 12 place of this string.
Then we assing to a `town` a slice of this `line` as `line[:(index_to_par - 1)]` - we want to have values from begining of the string (as there is no value in front of `:`) to a our `index_to_par - 1` (so all values before first occurence of `(`). You can read more about string sliceing here ---> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3

Comment: I would be grateful if you can more tell me about this line?     town = line[:(line.index('(')-1)]

Comment: I replay in my answer edit as in comments there is a character limit.

Comment: thank you very much